# Amazon Textract for iOS and Android Apps

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, ocr

I intend to use AWS Textract services in the mobile app - iOS and Android. Can anyone tell me how exactly can this be used to develop the OCR functionality in mobile apps ?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you can use this unofficial SDK for Amazon AWS services, including Textract: https://github.com/soto-project/soto